# SQL Server date Format user dependent?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query with hard coded dates, in this format

```
startdate >= '2012-11-03' AND enddate <= '2012-11-30 23:59'
```

My database date format is 'mdy', however I'm sure it will accept yyyy-mm-dd as its the universal date structure.

When I try run this query in SSMS on my target DB connected with a specific database user (userX) I get an error about the date formats

> *Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>
> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

However, when I run the exact query connected as the SA user, the query executes..

Why is this? I have given userX full dbo permissions (sysadmin etc) and still get the error?

Comment: Not sure what the reason for not working one user. However, *ISO date format* is `yyyymmdd` and *ISO8601 format* is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`. Try using them and see if you still get errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to specify datetimes using strings, you should use a **safe**, language-independent format.

In SQL Server, that's the ISO-8601 format (slightly adapted), and it supports basically two safe formats for `DATETIME` that always work - regardless of your language, regional and dateformat settings:

```
YYYYMMDD              (e.g. 20121231  for 31st of December 2012)  if you need date only

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss   (e.g. 2012-12-31T21:05:00 for 31st of December 2012, 9:05pm)
```

Note:

- the first date-only format has **no dashes** or delimiters!
- the second format has dashes for the date (can be omitted, too), and there's a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and the time portion of the string

**Update:** as per your last comment (on the different default languages for the two users) - try this:

```
-- this is how your `SA` interprets the string as datetime....
SET LANGUAGE english
SELECT CAST('2012-11-30 23:59' AS DATETIME)
```

Works just fine...

```
-- this is how your British user interprets teh string as datetime
SET LANGUAGE british
SELECT CAST('2012-11-30 23:59' AS DATETIME)
```

> *Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 7
>
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.*

This tries to interpret the string as *11th of the 30th month of 2012* and obviously, that fails....

Comment: Hi Marc, I appreciate your answer as it does work, however i'm confused that my first date strings don't work for one user but they work for the SA user?

Comment: @davey: do the `SA` and the other user have the same language settings ?

Comment: @davey: in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, in the `Object Explorer > (your server) > Security > Logins` and then look at the two logins in question (`SA` and your other user) - what is their `Default language` set to??

Comment: Ahhh.. just spotted that, sa is just english the other user is british english i shall swap and report back..Thats done it ... Dam hating myself for not seeing that. Thanks Marc

Answer (score 0):

consider using

> startdate >= '2012-11-03' AND enddate < '2012-12-01'

instead