# Does changing the Windows Server 2008 "Region and language" > Format setting have any impact on a SQL Server 2008 R2 database engine installed on it?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008

I've found at [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/4cc28f9e-9036-49aa-80d1-4148670c7266/) that

> The database engine doesn't care about regional settings

But I haven't found any documentation supporting this statement. For example, would it change the way it displays (or the way I edit) date, time or currencies in SSMS?

It seems like it won't, since dates in the database are totally different to the sample dates shown in the Formats tab. But, I would like to have more reading on this before having to restart my server many times (which is expensive for me).

Comment: I believe SQL server has its own completely independent configuration of this kind of thing. But I'm not positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is no, indeed, as stated in MSDN.

More precisely, **would it change the way it displays (or the way I edit) date, time or currencies in SSMS?**

Again, no. It has to do with the user language setting, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13845341/1863970) answer.

Answer (score 0):

In most case it does, because the regional settings of the operating system apply to virtually all applications installed on a computer system, and that includes the SSMS. The likes of Currency, Date format etc. Though SSMS has its own datetime format, its sometime also depends on the configuration of these applications in relation to your network setup.