# SQL Server Incorrectly Parsing Date

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM abc WHERE aDate = '2014-01-20'
```

When querying the above in SSMS it would normally return results where aDate is 20 January 2014. However for another user on the same server, it returns a date conversion error and only works when running the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM abc WHERE aDate = '2014-20-01'
```

I've checked regional language settings on the local machine and it's exactly the same as mine. Any ideas welcomed.

Comment: how do the users access the server? directly in SSMS?

Comment: Why not use an unambiguous format, such as `yyyyMMdd` (no separators)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server date Format user dependent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844870/sql-server-date-format-user-dependent)

Comment: Check each database user's language setting (in SSMS you can use the Object browser to look under Server/Security/Logins.) How to query unambiguously is explained well in the question I've marked as a duplicate.

Comment: In addition to the unseparated date format @Damien_The_Unbeliever suggested, the ISO format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` can be used for datetime/datetime2 literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was account specific, the setting was stored as 'British - English' as opposed to 'English'. Changing this to 'English' resolved the problem. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the regional language settings on the machine that count in this case but the one defined on the database's options.

Anyway, to avoid having to rely on the regional language settings when parsing datetime in queries I would encourage you to use an invariant ISO date format : `{d 'yyyy-MM-dd'}`. Note there is also one for specifying the hours (`ts`).

Answer (score -4):

This error occurred as the SQL server tries parse the date value 20 as month and it causes error as 20 is not a valid month .Always It is good practice to use the date format 'dd-MMM-yyyy' which will work with any type of SQL COLLATION and regional language settings.

Comment: Huh? If you use `dd-MMM-yyyy` format, you have to use (abbreviated) month names that match the regional language settings. How does that help?

Comment: Yes. you have to use abbreviated month names like '27-Oct-2015'. I don't think this abbreviated name will differ based on the regional settings.

Comment: @SudharsanamMuthukrishnan Set your session language to Italian and then try to use '27-Oct-2015'. It'll fail, because the abbreviation for October in Italian is "ott" (for "ottobre"), not "Oct". `20151027` will work fine for every language setting.